# Reading Numbers (integers and decimals) from file w/period as delimiter

Tags: c, scanf

Currently, I wanted to fetch the file with delimiter `.`. However, the using fscanf unable to differentiate decimals and integers.

Wanting to extract first two integers (separated by `.`) and the final decimals into `tmp[]`

Tried `fscanf(file,` **"%d."**`, &tmp[j]);` with `%d`, `%d.` and `%f`, neither had worked.

---

Result with `%d`: `tmp[3]: {1.61149323e-43, 0, 0.409999996}`

Result with `%d.`: `tmp[3]: {1.61149323e-43, 5.7453237e-44, 24.3600006}`

Result with `%f`: `tmp[3]: {115.410004, 24.3600006, 113.489998}`

`%d` and `%d.` [0] and [1] got gibberish, only `%d.` [3] got to be seems read right.
`%f` seems reading good, but it fused in the first two numbers into one decimals.

Do I had to use `fgets()` or `fgetc()`? or I can just change `fscanf()` format specifier to get it right?

---

Expected Result: (in debugger)

```
tmp[0]: 115
tmp[1]: 41
tmp[2]: 24.36

(file line 2 as input)
tmp[0]: 113
tmp[1]: 49
tmp[2]: 44
```

Source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    FILE *file = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    float tmp[3] = {};
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            fscanf(file, "%d.", &tmp[j]);
        }
        fscanf(file, "%f", &tmp[2]);
}
```

Data.txt

```
115.41.24.360
113.49.44
115.41.51.573
```

Comment: You can't use `%d` with a pointer to a float. If your compiler isn't complaining, turn up warning options until it does (`-Wall -Wextra` if using GCC or clang)

Comment: @Shawn Ohh that's why my compiler is kinda quiet these days, not even a warning. Gotta add that back. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%d` conversion specification is for reading a decimal integer, and expects an `int *` argument.  Similarly, the `%i`, `%o`, `%u`, `%x` and `%X` conversion specifications are also for integers.

Using `%f` is not going to work; it will read the 'second integer' as the fraction part of the first floating-point value, and there's no way to stop it doing that (unless you can safely use `%3f` because there'll always be at most 3 digits — which is a dubious proposition).

You'll need to use

```
int i1, i2;
if (fscanf(file, "%d.%d.%f", &i1, &i2, &tmp[2]) != 3)
{
    …handle error…
}
tmp[0] = i1;
tmp[1] = i2;
```

This reads the integer values into `int` variables, then assigns the results to the `float` array elements.  Note that you should always check the return value from `fscanf()` and friends.  If it isn't what you expect, there's a problem (as long as your expectations are correct, which they will be once you've read the specification for [`fscanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) often enough — a couple of times a day for the first couple of days, once a day for the next week, once a week for the next month, and about once a month for the next year).

Comment: Just curious, its that a reason to use two more integer variables `i1` and `i2`?

Comment: Well, you can't use `float` variables — you've already demonstrated that it doesn't work.  So you must use `int` variables of some sort.  I suppose that if you have a couple of spare variables around (why?), you could use them instead, but it is best to use each variable for one purpose, and `i1` and `i2` are for reading the first two integer components of the data you are trying to parse.  I'd be tempted to put the code into a (small) function so that those variables are local to that function, but you have probably not reached that level of wariness yet. A lot depends on your error handling.

Comment: I'm assuming that you need an array of 3 `float` values at the end of the input.  If you need some other set of types, then there probably alternative options.  But while you need an array of 3 `float` types, this is (I think)  more or less the simplest way to achieve the result.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have to handle multiple types as a single object, you should be thinking `struct` to provide storage. Here you have two integers and a float you want to store. A simple struct allowing that would be:

```c
typedef struct {        /* struct to hold data from line */
  int n1, n2;
  float f;
} twointf;
```

The `typedef` is for convenience allowing you to refer to `twointf` as the type instead of repeating `struct twointf` each time. With a struct, you can now declare a simple array of `twointf` to handle as many as needed.

To read you data, reading an entire line with `fgets()` into into a sufficiently sized buffer (character array) and parsing with `sscanf()` is always preferred over a direct read with `fscanf()`. If there is an error in your data file, `fgets()` will read the entire line into the buffer and the error will only effect a single line of data. With `fscanf()` a *Matching-Failure* can occur, or your read will wrap to the next line with an omitted value corrupting your read from that point forward in the file.

To read with `fgets()` and separate with `sscanf()` you can do:

```c
#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXS   32
...
    char buf[MAXC];                       /* read buffer for line */
    size_t ndx = 0;                       /* array of struct index */
    twointf arr[MAXS] = {{ .n1 = 0 }};    /* array of struct */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    ...
    /* while array not full, read line */
    while (ndx < MAXS && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {
      if (sscanf (buf, "%d.%d.%f",    /* separate into 2 int and float */
                  &arr[ndx].n1, &arr[ndx].n2, &arr[ndx].f) == 3) {
        ndx++;    /* on success, increment index */
      }
    }
```

That's all there is to it. Read your data, convert with `sscanf()` validating the return and only incrementing your array index on successful conversion of all values.

Putting it altogether you could do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define MAXS   32

typedef struct {        /* struct to hold data from line */
  int n1, n2;
  float f;
} twointf;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];                       /* read buffer for line */
    size_t ndx = 0;                       /* array of struct index */
    twointf arr[MAXS] = {{ .n1 = 0 }};    /* array of struct */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    /* while array not full, read line */
    while (ndx < MAXS && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {
      if (sscanf (buf, "%d.%d.%f",    /* separate into 2 int and float */
                  &arr[ndx].n1, &arr[ndx].n2, &arr[ndx].f) == 3) {
        ndx++;    /* on success, increment index */
      }
    }
    
    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ndx; i++)  /* output results */
        printf ("\narr[%zu].n1 = %d\narr[%zu].n2 = %d\narr[%zu].f  = %.2f\n",
                i, arr[i].n1, i, arr[i].n2, i, arr[i].f);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample data in `dat/data_int_float.txt`, you would have:

```
$ ./bin/twointf dat/data_int_float.txt

arr[0].n1 = 115
arr[0].n2 = 41
arr[0].f  = 24.36

arr[1].n1 = 113
arr[1].n2 = 49
arr[1].f  = 44.00

arr[2].n1 = 115
arr[2].n2 = 41
arr[2].f  = 51.57
```

(you can use the `%g` format specifier for floating-point to only output the decimal places if fractional data exists -- up to you)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on using struct, it's will complicated my code structure if used. The example still works tho, many thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Learning C is a journey, not a race. You will learn the benefits of `struct` in time. Using separate arrays is fine, -- it's just up to you to coordinate the indexes between them. Good luck with your coding.